# ERROR 1064 (42000) in creating table using MySQL 8.0 command line

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a table Order but somehow I am encountering the error code below:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order(
OrderId int,
CustId int,
OrderDate datetime,
RequiredDate datetime,
Shipp' at line 1
```

I use the following code to create my table:

```
create table Order(
-> OrderId int,
-> CustId int,
-> OrderDate datetime,
-> RequiredDate datetime,
-> ShippedDate datetime,
-> Status varchar(12),
-> Comments varchar(255)
-> );
```

We don't need to set primary key or foreign key but I don't know what went wrong with my code. Please advice thanks!

Comment: `ORDER` is a reserved word, needs to be delimited if used as a table name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: Btw do you have suggestion on where I can learn sql for free. Currently I'm using codecademy.

Comment: You do need a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jarlh I didn't know it was a reserve word. I just started SQL.